# postfix suddenly failed to expand mail aliases

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, aliases

I have used postfix on vine-linux legacy machine names "vine.domain.com (@ 210.251.xx.xx/28)" and have set mailalias on /etc/aliases:

> mike: xxx_xxxxx@gmail.com

for a long time. I have put $mydestination entry on /etc/postfix/main.cf

> mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain $mydomain, somedomain.to

So usually postfix on vine.domain.com receives emails to "mike@somedomain.to" and passes through to "xxx_xxxxx@gmail.com".

After we have just incremented serial of DNS record @somedomain.to, suddenly vine.domain.com fails email transfer from vine.domain.com to MX.gmail.com. Here /var/log/maillog says:

> Jul 19 17:53:29 vine postfix/smtp[14423]: 457C3C5FED: to=, relay=none, delay=0, status=bounced (Name service error for gmail.com: Host found but no data record of requested type)

When we works well, the maillog was like this:

> Jul 14 16:14:32 vine postfix/local[27176]: 7C759C6408: to=, relay=local, delay=0, status=sent(forwarded as B4070C6410)
>
> Jul 14 16:14:34 vine postfix/smtp[27198]: B4070C6410: to=, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27], delay=2, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1468488457 sl8si2007458pab.264 - gsmtp

I wonder that this trouble came from DNS issues @vine.domain.com, but I can not find where I correct the trouble first. I can not find proper information in terms of the issue on this website.

Here is a result of postfix -n . Thank you for your sincere support.

> bash# /usr/sbin/postconf -n
>
> alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases, hash:/var/spool/ml/etc/aliases
>
> alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases, hash:/var/spool/ml/etc/aliases
>
> allow_mail_to_commands = alias,forward,include
>
> allow_percent_hack = no
>
> command_directory = /usr/sbin
>
> daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
>
> debug_peer_level = 2
>
> default_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
>
> default_privs = fml
>
> inet_interfaces = all
>
> local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
>
> mail_owner = postfix
>
> mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
>
> mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain $mydomain, somedomain.to
>
> mydomain = domain.com
>
> myhostname = vine.domain.com
>
> mynetworks = 210.251.xx.xx/28, 127.0.0.0/8
>
> mynetworks_style = subnet
>
> myorigin = $mydomain
>
> queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
>
> relay_domains = $mydestination
>
> smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name ($mail_version)
>
> virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

Comment: Did you have SPF or DKIM records pointing to those older DNS records?

Comment: No, but since I have learned that we should put SPF info on the DNS at "somedomain.to", I have put new TXT record at "somedomain.to" after we have experienced this trouble on vine.domain.com.
Here the current TXT record at "somedomain.to" when I ask to nslookup right now.

` somedomain.to text = "v=spf1 +ip4:210.251.xx.yy/28 ~all" `

Comment: Usually we ask if you could put your domains in the question, as it helps to  diagnose DNS errors.. as I'm 99% sure this is a DNS error, as gmail is complaining about your records.. have you got an RDNS record for `vine.domain.com`, and an A and MX record also?

Comment: Thank you. vine.domain.com stands for vine.mju.jp(210.251.89.106). And, somedomain.to stands for mike.to. vine.mju.jp is currently same as vine.mike.to. We have set up an NS calls itedu.mju.jp(210.251.89.98). vine.mju.jp is supposed to forward emails arrived at an account on vine.mike.to toward gmail email account.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the actual domain :)

I think your problem may be that you don't have an `MX` record for `mjp.jp`

> dig -t mx mju.jp
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> -t mx mju.jp ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got
>   answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32458 ;;
>   flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;mju.jp.      IN       MX
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: mju.jp.                 300     IN      SOA
>   01.dnsv.jp. hostmaster.dnsv.jp. 1468466454 3600 900 604800 30

Since your server announces itself as `vine.mjp.jp` there needs to be a `data record of requested type` (one specifying who is the mail server) for the mjp.jp domain.

You might also want to see if you can get a `PTR` record set up for that IP, as it will improve delivery possibilities

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be deleted and there isn't any MX record on mju.jp although I suppose we have a MX record on mju.jp in the past. I will ask to NS officer of mju.jp and reenter

Comment: Let us know what happens when it's put up again..